Safety concerns with this Antenna in close proximity?
Brand new amateur radio license holder, and I (still) know next to nothing. As I posted in a previous thread, I recently got my mobile radio: Anytone D578UVIIIPlus. This base station accessory bundle that I also got, came with this vertical antenna: AnyTone Tri-band Mobile DMR Antenna.
Today, I put together my antenna and attached it to the magnetic mount in the above bundle and I've attached that mount to a metal cookie sheet. It's currently on a desk just a couple of feet away from me and my radio. Stability looks good.
Eventually, I'll try it in my attic, but I was thinking of running some tests with the antenna on my desk where it is, but I'm not sure of the safety implications with it being that close. I know RF burns are a thing. But assuming I'm careful not to touch it while transmitting etc, are there any other safety concerns with the antenna being that close?
Thanks in advance!

Note that a cookie sheet is likely about half the size required to be a good ground plane.   The ground plane should be about as big as the antenna is long.

Congrats and welcome to the hobby!

Note that quite generally, radio signals like free space and don't like obstacles. While the amplitude one the effet varies with the characteristics of the signal and of the obstacles, having your antenna outside (and the radio as close as possible to avoid losses in cabling) will enable you have the same (or better) results while using less power (and thus less risk to anything close to the antenna).

Welcome to the hobby! You're now allowed to experiment with potentially dangerous RF. It's smart to use an RF exposure calculator such as this ARRL one or this one from the RSGB to make sure you're operating safely.
In the long term
RF dangers increase with power levels and antenna gain. They decrease with cable loss and modes. Your antenna has a gain of "3.5dBi on 144MHz 4.5dBi on 220MHz 6dBi on 440MHz", so 6 dBi worst case. Your radio goes up to 50 W. Your cable is pretty short, so probably not too much loss. FM is a 100% power mode. Assuming you transmit 50% of the time, the RSGB says you should be 3.2 m from the antenna for safe long-term operation.
If you want to be safe at a shorter distance, you can turn the power down - operate at 25 W, 10 W or 5 W.
For now
A quick transmission or two at 50 W won't cause much trouble. Go for it. Just don't chat for hours, and avoid touching the antenna when you're transmitting. Reduce power as much as you can - it's good practice to use the lowest power required for communication.
Indoors 50 W may cause some electronics to misbehave, so you might want distance between any implanted medical devices and the antenna if you have them.

IEEE (North America/FCC) and ICNIRP (Europe) exposure standards differ: IEEE is more restrictive than ICNIRP at HF, and is less restrictive starting at VHF. To be compliant, you should use the calculator and formulas corresponding to your jurisdiction.
